# preg_match validation warning

Tags: php, javascript, preg-match

I have a regular expression that validates 10 digit Indian mobile numbers beginning with either 7 or 8 or 9. Below is the folllowing code I have written:

```
if(!preg_match("/(^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$)/", $mobile))
{
                        return false;
}
```

where $mobile holds the 10 digit mobile number. However I get a warning **Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0**

Cant really figure out whats wrong here! Help!

Comment: What is value of $mobile?

Comment: `{1}` isn't needed, you can remove it

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you have to write your regex like that : `/^([7-9]{1}[0-9]{9})$/` if you need to checks brackets.
Else, `/^[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/` will work the same.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the brackets were a problem!

Comment: You can write `(^[7-9][0-9]{9}$)` too with parenthesis as delimiters of the pattern